# PHP curl response time

Tags: php, api, curl

I am doing a php curl which works fine on command line. I got an answer after a short amount of time.

But when I call the same function on the web browser I am getting a blank response.

is there a way to make the browser service waiting for an answer before print the blank response as the command line does?

Comment: show your code and clarify the question please.  unsure what a `php curl` is in your context.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question the delay was due that my ip wasn't registered with the server we were meant to communicate with, causing obviously the delay in the feedback.